# Speed up removal of first two letters in attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a number of layers, each with around 325,000 rows of data. I wish to remove the first two letters within a column, leaving only the numbers (e.g. amend "SP99612" to "99612"). I have tried to run the simple expressions `right("CircuitID",5)` or `substr("CircuitID",3,5)` but it is taking hours to run.

[image: Table example]

I have created a new column named "CircuitID2" to add the amended data in the hope that creating this field prior to the calculation would speed the process up (it didn't). I've also closed the attribute table and ran the field calculator from the main window to see if that would speed it up (it hasn't).

The Geodatabase is saved on my OneDrive and is spatial data.

Comment: Network latency is likely destroying performance. Try copying locally, doing the edit, then copying over the previous data.

Comment: To add to @Vince's comment, I ran an update like yours with 325000 records on an in-memory layer and it took a few seconds.

Comment: After copying onto my C drive it processed in seconds - thanks - I should have checked that first!